# whay is it error? (using online sql lite)

Tags: sql, sqlite

This doesn't seem to be a problem
But when I use all or some, Error is appeared. I use Online SQL interpreter.
[enter image description here][1]

```
select name
from instructor
where salary > all (select salary from instructor where dept name = 'Biology');
```

Uncaught Error: near "all": syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reformatting the where as:

```
select name
from instructor
where salary > (select max(salary) from instructor where dept name = 'Biology');
```

"Where bigger than all" is the same as "where bigger than the biggest".

Comment: That is the same solution as here : "Does this answer your question? SQLite syntax for "ALL" – 
pringi  9 mins ago"

Comment: That's true - I don't Google for the solution to simple questions when the asker has tried and git stuck. It takes longer than answering.

Comment: I understand, I was not addressing to you to suggest to you to google it next time. I wanted to point out to you that there was already a comment to this question and that comment has a link that leads to the same answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT name
FROM instructor
WHERE deptname = 'Biology'
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The OP's subject is : "whay is it error? (using online sql lite)"